# Which of the four fundamental forces is responsible for covalent bonds?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, physical-chemistry, atoms, molecules

Molecules are the result of covalent bonds forming between atoms.

Which of the four fundamental forces is responsible for covalent bonding?

(Sorry if this is basic -- I'm guessing electromagnetic, but just wanted to check.)

Comment: have you heard of molecular orbital theory ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Covalent bonds are EM (electrostatic/electronegativity) or not?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/487114/covalent-bonds-are-em-electrostatic-electronegativity-or-not)

Comment: I think the answers given, as well as the suggested existing answer, are misleading. While electromagnetic interaction is an essential ingredient of covalent bonding,  one cannot by pass the exchange interaction, since otherwise there is no way of meaningfully distinguishing covalent bonds from other types, such as ionic, metallic or even hydrogen bonds - all of which are of electromagnetic origin.

Answer (score 0):

Electromagnetism.

If you want to learn more, you might be interested in this question as well: [Why do covalent bonds form?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35408/why-do-covalent-bonds-form?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is electromagnetic.

In spite of the simple answer, we can deepened your question. Covalent bonds consists of sharing electrons between two different atoms. Electrons are attracted to the atom nucleus by the electromagnetic force. The covalent bond happens when two atoms are close to each other and their electrons start to be bounded to both nucleus.